# things that prevent cross-platformness your java web application

Tags: java, cross-platform

are there any things that once can do ignorantly that can prevent a java web application from being cross platform? (windows/linux/mac)

Tools I am planning to use are java/spring framework/hibernate

Answer (score 12):

- Hard-coding file separators/paths.
- Using native libraries.
- Using Runtime.exec()
- Using sun.* classes (this may cause portability issues with non-Sun JVMs).

Comment: +1 for the hard-coding of file separators -- those are brain-dead killers on a lot of apps that have no reason otherwise not to work cross-platform.

Comment: Using `sun.*` (and most `com.sun.*`) classes may well cause portability between update releases. Don't do it!

Comment: how would you not hard code seperators? using a .xml config file or?

Comment: @mrblah: try java.io.File.separator

Answer (score 6):

not honoring case-sensitivity in filesystem

Answer (score 6):

Using system default character encoding for input/output when inappropriate

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Dan Dyer said:

- calling executables by a fixed path or of a fixed name
- assuming a certain shell command syntax will work properly (eg `2>&1` or something)
- deleting or renaming a file that some other process (or the same one!) might have open
- Making assumptions about the working directory (eg using relative paths to load resouces from the file system)